# CSV writer goes to next line for each input value

Tags: python, csv, newline

I am new to Python. I am trying to write numbers in a CSV file. The first number makes the first element of the row. Second number second and then a new row should start. However, the way that my code works, instead of adding the second element to the same row, it makes a new row.

For instance what I want is:

```
a1,b1
a2,b2
```

But what I get is:

```
a1
b1
a2
b2
```

I use a loop to continuously write values into a CSV file:

```
n = Ratio # calculated in each loop
with open('ex1.csv', 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([n])
    ...

m = Ratio2 # calculated in each loop
with open('ex1.csv', 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([m])
```

I would like the results to be in format of

```
n1,m1
n2,m2
```

Comment: Then join together `n` and `m`, i.e. `writer.writerow([n, m])`

Comment: You might need to specify the delimiter as ','

Comment: A [Clomplete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful to reproduce your issue more easily.

Comment: You are opening the file every time and append to it - open it once out of the loop. Collect all your `n` s inside a list per row you want to write and once the row is completely in the list use `writer.writerow( yourList )` - it will automagically write each element of the list and a dividerchar behind that.

Answer (score 1):

Example for writing to a file and then reading it back and printing it:

```
import csv

with open('ex1.csv', 'w') as f: # open file BEFORE you loop
    writer = csv.writer(f)      # declare your writer on the file

    for rows in range(0,4):     # do one loop per row
        myRow = []              # remember all column values, clear list here
        for colVal in range(0,10):   # compute 10 columns
            m = colVal * rows        # heavy computing  (your m or n)
            myRow.append(m)          # store column in row-list

        writer.writerow(myRow)  # write list containing all columns 

with open('ex1.csv', 'r') as r:  #read it back in 
    print(r.readlines())         # and print it
```

Output:

```
['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\r\n', '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\r\n', '0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18\r\n', '0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27\r\n']
```

which translates to a file of

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18
0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27
```

You can also stuff each rows list (copy it by `myList[:]`) into another list and use `writer.writerows([ [1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7] ])` to write all your rows in one go .

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects or https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects